# Accessing a service using a LoadBalancer in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, microk8s

When exposing a service in minikube it is possible to see its url via the following:

```
minikube service [-n NAMESPACE] [--url] NAME
```

How do you achieve the same in microk8s?

Thank you

Comment: I've not used microk8s but get the impression there's not a direct equivalent. See comments on how to access services in https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/95 and https://itnext.io/microk8s-puts-up-its-istio-and-sails-away-104c5a16c3c2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realizing this is an older post, but since I just recently implemented a dev install of MicroK8s, I though perhaps I could provide some of my findings.

Wanting a load balancer, I installed MetalLB, https://metallb.universe.tf/, which provides a baremetal LB for a cluster. While MicroK8s does offer an addon for this, I did a manual installation to help myself gain a better understanding.

I used the Layer 2 Configuration option, https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration which provided a very simple way to expose my services via a load balancer.

To use the config, I then added an annotation to the services that utilize it, indicating which address pool, which for my deployment, I simply call microk8s_pool.

```
metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: microk8s_pool
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about microk8s, but in minikube you'd be able to see LoadBalancer services' IP addresses once you run "**minikube tunnel**" in a separate command shell (and keep it open). Running minikube tunnel, gets the LoadBalancer services exposed to the outsize and then you can see the IPs through "minikube service".

```
minikube service [-n NAMESPACE] Name
```